# Handle "type" as a key in JSON while deserializing to JSON in complex object

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a JSON that's similar to the following that I want to deserialize into case classes,

```
{"a": 1, "type": "A", "properties": { "b": 2, "type": "B", "customProperty": {} }}
```

The corresponding case classes have Type instead of type as a member because type is a reserved property.

```
case class A(a: String, Type: String, properties: AProperties)
case class AProperties(b: String, Type: String, customProperty: CustomProperty)
case class CustomProperty()
```

withcolumnrenamed seems to work well for a single level however not for the recursive hierarchy.

Following are my questions:
- Is there any way I can declare "type" as a member in the case class ?
- How do I go about deserializing JSON as by renaming type as Type ?

Comment: Try adding backticks for `type`

Comment: Do you have this jason as a string in a column or read json into a datafame and want to convert that dataframe to a caseclass dataset

Comment: The file i'm trying to load is a JSON file. The solution given by @blackbishop is perfect.